# Eating medicine while fasting will make the fast makrooh?

Tags: sawm, medical, makruh

I have to eat anti epileptic medicine at 8:00 AM and 8:00 PM. This cannot be delayed not even for 10 minutes. So if I eat my medicine while fasting, will it make my fast makrooh?

Comment: hmm I see, 12 hrs gap, can u do the same when you're not fasting during the night... Oops, again, It might depend on where you live I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
            In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

It could be surveyed from two different angles:

- It would be considered as a haram practice, and will invalidate the
  fasting, since eating and drinking will invalidate the fasting (in
  the cases that it is not so necessary to take medicine).
- It would invalidate the fasting, but Kafara-jam’ is not wajib for him
  or her. Actually s/he solely do its Qaza.

**On the whole, taking medicine will invalidate the fasting, but there is different for the amount of its Qaza.**

---

References:

- [www.bahjat.ir](http://www.bahjat.ir/index.php/ahkam/esteftahat/151-2011-09-06-09-34-02.html)
- [www.saafi.net](http://saafi.net/fa/node/4682)

Answer (score 2):

The majority of scholars say that if it is an injection, it is OK since it goes into the blood stream and not into the stomach. However; a growing number of scholars are saying even pills are OK since it is medicine, like the following Moroccan scholar:

- [www.doualia.com](http://www.doualia.com/2010/08/22/medicaments-pendant-le-ramadan-ninvalide-pas-le-jeune/)

Comment: but most of the medication are prescribed to be taken after eating something and generally we take pill with water to swallow easily.

Comment: Even if i would disagree with Sheikh az-Zamzami (The morrocan scholar mentioned in the article)  i think one should consider that in some cases (as in the Question as far as i understand), people are able to fast but have to take medicine in exactly the same Time/date each day! And why should they be "punished" (by doing kafara etc.) because they break their fast?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot eat any medicine while fasting. It will break the fast.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this fatwa](http://fasting%20medicine) you can take necessary medecine during fast.

According to [this fatwa](http://Patient%20needs%20to%20take%20medication%20whilst%20fasting), you cannot fast.

You should read [this](http://%20Fasting%20in%20Ramadan%20%E2%80%93%20A%20Muslim%20Pharmacist%E2%80%99s%20Perspective%20Answered%20according%20to%20Hanafi%20Fiqh%20by%20Qibla.com) longer fatwa respecting medical issues.
Saying «Alternative routes of drug administration can help fasting patients», it implicitly allows taking medicine during fast, and recommends to **consult the doctor** to councel whether fasting is adequate.

Comment: All links are invalid urls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will break your fast, But since you HAVE TO eat the medicine, you will have to pay Fidyah, which Varies depending where and why.