# Can I take my medication while fasting?

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, ramadan

I have strep throat and I need to take medication for it. Does it break my fast if I take the medication? I dont want to give my family strep throat, but I also don’t want to break my fast. I have to take it 3 times a day. What should I do?

BTW, Happy Ramadan

Comment: What type of medication you take?

Comment: This could have an answer in [Eating medicine while fasting will make the fast makrooh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24602/eating-medicine-while-fasting-will-make-the-fast-makrooh)

Comment: I have added an answer in https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24602/eating-medicine-while-fasting-will-make-the-fast-makrooh; you may read the links there. However your case is different, and most scholars would say that you should not take the medecine while fast as it is not necessary to you health.